# How can I use a variable as an expect value in an Expect script (expect -re regex)

Tags: linux, expect

I have an expect script where I do not always know the output, nor do I want to hardcode the expected output returned from a given command, instead I pass in a part of the expected output as a command line variable. I then want to use the expected output as part of a regex to validate against.

I've looked at a few examples and can only see cli vars being used with the send command but not with the expect -re command.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set output [lindex $argv 0]
set host [lindex $argv 1]

set regex "{(?n)^${output}.*}"
puts $regex

set timeout -1

spawn ssh root@$host
expect -re {(?n)^Password.*}

send "myPassword\n"
expect -re $regex

expect eof
```

OUTPUT

```
Password: couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid
    while executing
"expect -re $regex"
```

EXPECTED
Regex should be handled as a the value set in the output cli variable.

Note well: when values are hardcoded the script works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Braces in a regular expression are quantifier syntax. For example, to find 3 "a", you can use `a{3}`

Your assignment of the $regex variable contains literal braces

```
set regex "{(?n)^${output}.*}"
```

expect is an extension of the Tcl language: in Tcl, you use double quotes to enclose a "word" allowing variable and command substitution; you use braces to enclose a word with no substititions allowed (like single quotes in the shell).

Simply remove the braces from the $regex value.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, when the above expect script is ran with the first it fails and and when the string in hardcoded to the regex it works. Any idea why this is happening? 


`set regex {(?n)^${output}.*}


set regex_text {(?n)^Error.*}`


Error:

`expect: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"expect eof"`

Comment: Tcl won't expand variables inside braces. Use double quotes instead. And while developing your code, debug using `expect -d`

Comment: Great that worked nicely thanks, for anyone that is as green on the subject as myself here is what I had to change it too. I set the regex as `(?n)^${output}.*` instead of `{(?n)^${output}.*}`